# After submitting a form which contains one or more file input field, only last input is being submitted

Tags: forms, file, dom, file-upload

I have made `form` tag with only one `input` , which is of type `file`. I am dynamically adding more file `inputs`. But after submitting only last `input` type is being transmitted as `POST` request.
How can I make it to transfer all file inputs?

```
<form name="file_upload" id="file_upload" action="/upload/validate_save"enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" onSubmit="return validate_file_extension()"> 

    <%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token -%> 
    <div id="dynamic_file_browse"> <input id="file1" name="file" type="file"/>    
    <input id="file2" name="file" type="file"/> </div> 
    <input type="button" id="add_more_files" value="add" onClick="add_file()"/>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    <input name="commit" id="commit" type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can add more details, like code, to your question by using the [edit] button. I have done that for you. I have also used the [tag:html] tag to help the right experts find your question.

Comment: All the inputs will be submitted. Your form parsing library is just ignoring some of them. How you deal with that depends on which form parsing library you're using. Most will have some method to access all fields with duplicate names as an array instead of as a single field.

Comment: With input fields, the `name` attribute counts, not the ID. The fields you are adding all seem to overwrite each other because they are using the same name. Use differing `name` attributes.

Comment: It worked after making name field dynamic too